# How to recreate an Index with the same settings?

Tags: t-sql, index, sql-server-2017

I'm in a situation where I want to add another included column to an existing index, but keep the rest of the settings (eg. FILLFACTOR, ONLINE, SORT_IN_TEMPDB, etc.) the same.

- I do not have the previous version in source control
- I didn't find most of them in sys.indexes DMV (FILLFACTOR is there, but not ONLINE)
- Finding the index in Object Explorer and scripting it out fills default values for the ONLINE setting (and omits DATA_COMPRESSION)
- I didn't find the property in the OBJECTPROPERTY DMF
- Brent Ozar's sp_BlitzIndex also doesn't provide some of these advanced settings
- sp_helpindex provides me with the same limited information as sp_help over the parent table.
- I cannot test if WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON) recreates the index with the same settings, because I can't find the settings anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried with [INDEXPROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/indexproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: @McNets I have not as I was not aware of it :). But reading the documentation it doesn't provide the properties I mentioned in my post (eg. ONLINE).

Comment: I don't think things like `ONLINE` and `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` are _properties_ of an index, but more like _instructions_ on _how_ to build/rebuild the index.  Once the index is built, those options are meaningless.

Comment: FYI `DROP_EXISTING = ON` removes settings such as a custom `FILL FACTOR`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably play with scripting options in `Tools-Options-SQL Server Object Explorer-Scripting` in `SSMS` menu.

There you can define what you would like to script and what not. `Compression` is there.

As for the other properties - have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505529/unable-to-set-sort-in-tempdb) `StackOverflow` question - it will probably shed some light:

`SORT_IN_TEMPDB` is not a property of an index, but rather an option that you can specify that says how the index is created. Once the index exists (i.e. the create index statement completes), whether or not `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` was specified at creation time isn't stored anywhere because it doesn't matter.